# Get contents of parent div from the child div and call a function on the button in child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

This is my ajax code to insert div dynamically with a remove button.

```
 $('#diplayContainerDiv').append('<div id="divQueryDisplay'+   divCounter +'">' +val1+val2+val3+ '</div><div id="removeButtonDiv"><input type="button" name="removeButton" id="removeButton'+  removeButtonCounter +'" value="Remove" onclick="removeRemoveButtonOnClick();" ></div>');
```

I am trying to call the following function on remove button

```
 function removeRemoveButtonOnClick(){
   //document.getElementById('#divQueryDisplay'+removeButtonCounter).innerHTML ="";  // this does not works
    var parentElement=document.getElementById('#diplayContainerDiv');
    var childElement= document.getElementById('#divQueryDisplay'+removeButtonCounter);   

    childElement.parentElement.removeChild(childElement);   

}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null
    at removeRemoveButtonOnClick 
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: from where you get `removeButtonCounter`?

Comment: It's a javascript variable which increments as the button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` takes the element id as the parameter, not an id selector

```
var parentElement=document.getElementById('diplayContainerDiv');
var childElement= document.getElementById('divQueryDisplay'+removeButtonCounter);
```

remove the `#`